# Click based upon value of hash on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to working with JS/jQuery, I've been currently trying to figure out how to make this work, by trying many different ways that I've found here and on different sites, and am unable to get this working.

I have a website that has tabs, that changes a div's content when the click on the buttons in the menu. This all works fine, but I want to be able to link to each separate "page" using hash tags example.com/#tab-1

HTML:

```
<div class="tabWrapper">
<div class="tabContent">
<div class="label">TAB 1</div>
<?php include 'tab1.php'; ?>
</div>
<div class="tabContent">
<div class="label">TAB 2</div>
<?php include 'tab2.php'; ?>
</div>
```

tabWrapper looks like this after being generated

```
<div class="tabWrapper">
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="tab-1">TAB 1</li>
<li class="tab-2">TAB 2</li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
    // Generate tab navigation
if ($('div.tabWrapper').length != 0)
{   
    $('div.tabWrapper').each(function()
    {
        // Prepare tab output
        var printTabs = '<ul class="tabs">';
        var tabContent =  $(this).find('.tabContent');
        var tabCount = tabContent.length;

        $(tabContent).each(function(key)
        {
            // Hide tab if it is not the first
            if (key != 0)
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }

            // Get label for tab
            var label = $(this).find('.label').text();

            // Use a number if no label was given           
            if (!label)
            {
                label = 'Tab ' + (key + 1);
            }

            // Add id to tab content
            $(this).addClass('tab-' + key);
            printTabs+= '<li class="tab-' + key + '">' + label + '</li>';
        });

        // Add tabs
        $(this).prepend(printTabs + '</ul>');
        $(this).find('li:first').addClass('active');
    });
}
// Handle click on tabs
$('.tabWrapper').delegate('ul.tabs li', 'click', function()
{
    // Deny click on active element
    if ($(this).is('.active'))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get tab id
    var id = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
    id = id[1];

    // Display and animate new tab content
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    parent.find('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    parent.find('.tabContent').hide()
    parent.find('.tab-' + id).animate({ opacity: 'show' }, animationSpeed);
});
```

Here is what I was trying to add, which I don't think is correct

```
function hash() {
    if(window.location.hash){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $("." + hash).click();
    }
}
```

which I added in the js file just above

```
$('.tabWrapper').delegate('ul.tabs li', 'click', function()
```

I'm not sure how far I'm off with that code, as it doesn't seem to work at all. I just want it to see if there is a hash tag in the url, and if there is then run the click function to change the content.

I hope I explained what I was looking for clear enough. I'd very much appreciate any help with this.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I updated the code with setInterval as per chiliNUT's suggestion, however it still doesn't appear to be working.

```
setInterval(hash,1000);
function hash() {
    if(window.location.hash){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $("." + hash).click();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Still unable to get this working, anyone able to help?

Thanks.

Comment: since a hash change isn't going to trigger a page load, you need to be regularly polling your `hash()` function. it looks like it will work as written if you add something like `setInterval(hash,1000);` that would check for hash changes everyt second

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that @chiliNUT I added it, (I believe correctly) still seems like adding a hash to the URL doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

My tip is using anchor tags as well.

```
<a href="#tab1">Link</a>
```

That will open example.com#tab1

The control on page load:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   if(window.location.hash == "#tab1"){
        $("#someId").click();
   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use anchor tags?

```
<a href="#tab1">Button to open tab 1</a>
```